# Sent user to page bottom by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send user to the bottom of page

by javascript

I am trying this code

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

it does not work

but if i try

```
window.scrollTo(0,9999999999999999);
```

it works very well

Is page height can be greater than `9999999999999999` ?

Or there is better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: @AlaaGamal—use both, e.g. `window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)`. Most browsers want the first, some the second.

Comment: A few years ago `document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;` was working at Google Chrome, now only `document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;` works.

Answer (score 2):

For Scroll down in Selenium use below code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
// (driver is your browser webdriver object)
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight)", "");
```

For scroll up use below code:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-document.body.scrollHeight || -document.documentElement.scrollHeight)", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always send them to `Number.MAX_VALUE`, that is guaranteed to be the biggest possible.