# Trigger $(window).scroll();

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, scrolltop

When I call `$("body").animate({scrollTop: someValue});` I want `$(window).scroll(function() { });` to be called too. How can I achieve that?

I have tried with `$(window).trigger("scroll")` and `$(window).triggerHandler("scroll")` without success.

[The code](http://pastebin.com/ewUmmUti)

**EDIT:**
Problem solved. There was an `if` in my `$(window).scroll(function() { });` that caused the problem.

Comment: what is animationType? And what if you use animationType inside inverted commas such as 'easeIn'?

Comment: @al0neevenings That is not the problem. The body section scrolls, but the `$(window).scrollU();` doesn't get called.

Comment: can you also post what the method bound to `scroll` is doing ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli oh... there was the problem. I had an if that prevented the function to run...

Answer (score 50):

Just use:

```
// Trigger the scroll event
$(window).scroll();
```

Source:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_scroll.asp
- https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 9):

Apply it to both `body` and `html` as it is not consistent.. (*for example, FF uses the `html` for scrolling while chrome uses the `body`*)

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: someValue});
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/vzyVh/

Comment: 1) Doesn't solve my problem.
2) Then the callback get called twice.

Comment: @sawny, only if you have specifically made your CSS to allow both `html` and `body` to scroll. By default only one of those scrolls..
Additionally: the `scroll` method applied to `window` is not called only once. It gets called for each scrolling step..

Comment: Mixed this answer with http://stackoverflow.com/a/12792245/1504300 for graceful scrolling to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code - here i am scrolling to top of my div tag which has id "one".

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#one').offset().top }, 'slow');
```